# How to make a jtextarea respond to another jtextarea change

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jtextarea

```
    JComboBox cBox = new JComboBox();
    cBox.addItem("Food"); String x = "Food";
    cBox.addItem("Shirt");
    cBox.addItem("Computer");
    cBox.setSelectedItem(null);
    cBox.setBounds(56, 127, 336, 27);
    contentPane.add(cBox);

    tPName = new JTextArea();
    tPName.setBounds(38, 227, 130, 26);
    contentPane.add(tPName);
    tPName.setColumns(10);

    tSName = new JTextArea();
    tSName.setBounds(262, 227, 130, 26);
    contentPane.add(tSName);
    tSName.setColumns(10);

    JButton btn = new JButton("Further Details");
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String name = (String) cBox.getSelectedItem(); //gets value of combo box
            tPName.setText(name); //text area displays value
            String x = (String) tPName.getText();
            name = "Food"; tSName.setText(F);
            name = "Shirt"; tSName.setText(S);
            name ="Computer"; tSName.setText(C);

        }
    });
    btn.setBounds(162, 166, 117, 29);
    contentPane.add(btn);
```

how would I make tSName display a text corresponding to a specific value of tPName which is copied from a combobox where F, S and C strings stand for those corresponding values I want to use.

Comment: place an Actionlistener as same as you did with the button. and set the corresponding text to it.  So as user hits enter  it will be called and you can change the value of TSname.

Comment: the user does not press enter they use a button to make the combobox add to the text area and I cant make a listener on a jtextarea

Comment: okay so what is the error you are getting exactly. We all over here will try to solve it :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. You try to make one textarea display something, when the text of another textarea changes, am I right? If yes, you should look for an Event of the first Textbox (something like `tPNameKeyTyped`) in this Event you can check the `tPName.getText()` simply with

```
if(tPName.getText().equals("whatever")){
   tSName.setText("whatever u want");
}
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: yes it is what I am looking for but when I do this I get an error tSName cannot be resolved

Comment: I fixed the error but the tSName textarea is still not receiving anything

Comment: Are u using eclypse GUI builder? if yes right click on the textarea tPName -> Events -> Key -> key typed.. this is how i get the event u want using netbeans, but i think its pretty simillar in eclypse. In this Event u use `tSName.setText("...");`

Answer (score 0):

I right now dont have pc so I cant check errors but.
this should work

```
 tPName.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            tSName.setText(tPName.getText()); // put the value of tPName to tSName.
            // i think this is all you want. i actually cant get your question.
           // you can put a switch case to put coreesponding values in tSName. like: 
     switch(tPName.getText()){
            case "a" : tSName.setText("1");
                         break;
            //..... so on
             default:
                      tSName.setText("stack overflow is great");
                         break;

         }
      }
    });
```

EDIT:- Onece you do this try to refresh and validate the textareas.

```
tPName.validate();
tSName.validate();
tPName.repaint(); // refresh  still not sure as i dont have pc if this not works try <your jframe>.repaint(); this should work
```

Comment: yeah I couldn't find a way to put action listener into a textarea so I used addKeyListener. for ur code im not sure what u mean by so on. there are no errors but the 2nd box is still not receiving anything

Comment: @kennymydude so on means you can put many other case like case "b".

Comment: where would I put the validate and repaint

Comment: @kennymydude after you change the text of tSName.

Comment: yes but the action listener does not work for jtextarea

Comment: But action listener in button and change text